# Xamarin build Error The "XamlCTask" task has been declared or used incorrectly

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I downloaded some exercise files from LinkedIn Learning. I'm trying to build the project from the files I downloaded and I get this error message:

```
Error The "XamlCTask" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. 
Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.
```

I have no idea what it's talking about. It also doesn't tell me much about where the error is occurring like a file name or code line so that's not very helpful. The only thing I have to go off of is that it's in the shared project. I also tried searching the entire solution for the text "XamlCTask" and it returned 0 results. What I've tried so far:

- Clean solution
- Rebuild solution

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Comment: Close your solution and delete the `packages` folder, if there is one.

Comment: Thanks @MihailDuchev ! That was so simple, it also got rid of 2 other errors I had. Solution and projects built.

Comment: I added it as an answer. You can mark it as correct, so that it can help others. Initially, I first was very confused when I encountered this issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your solution and delete the `packages` folder. This is a known issue/fix with "older" solutions.